# How to configure nginx to proxy by port and host with a different SSL certificate for each?

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy

(updated) I'd like to proxy requests like this:

```
https://port123.host.com:85/any/path ==> http://server85:123/any/path
https://port567.host.com:85/any/path ==> http://server85:567/any/path
https://port123.host.com:86/any/path ==> http://server86:123/any/path
https://port567.host.com:86/any/path ==> http://server86:567/any/path
```

How would you recommend I achieve this?
(I know it's a funny architecture)

The server declarations work without SSL, with it - not.

```
server {
    listen 86 ssl;
    server_name port123;
    ssl_certificate CERT123;
    ssl_...;
    localtion / { proxy_pass.... }
}

server {
    listen 86 ssl;
    server_name port567;
    ssl_certificate CERT567;
    ssl...;
    localtion / { proxy_pass.... }
}
```

I see it's a known limitation of nginx (multi SSLSs on single port and single IP). But I wonder if there's any simple workaround. I can't use SAN because every server I have is actually a wildcard with a wildcard certificate.

Comment: What is the practical purpose of this?

Comment: Use the directive proxy_pass

Comment: @Amir - Did you try the nginx config and if so did it work for you?

Comment: I updated the question with config details. I got it to work with HTTP but not with HTTPS. I also tried to separate the server declarations to different files which didn't help.

Comment: This is a different question from what you asked initially. If you're satisfied with the answer to your original question, please accept it. I think your new question about SSL configuration should be a separate question, since it's specific to SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it with a separate IP address for each SSL endpoint.
Since the TLS session takes place without the host header nginx can't "guess" which certificate to use. So IPs fix it, and I happen to have some available. So:

```
server {
    listen 192.168.1.5:85 ssl;
    server_name port123;
    ssl_certificate     /port123.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /port123.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://server85:123/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 192.168.1.6:86 ssl;
    server_name port123;
    ssl_certificate     /port567.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /port567.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://server86:567/;
    }
}
```

I actually have more combinations and I also set headers differently. But it finally works.

As always, nginx has the best articles: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: This is somewhat wrong... No nginx can't guess the name but providing you are using a browser that support SNI it doesn't need to. it is perfectly possible to use a single IP with multiple names/certs

Comment: Nginx doesn't "guess" which SSL certificate to use. It follows a set of rules established by its config file to determine which certificate(s) to use for each request.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a server block for each port that you want nginx to listen on. Within the server block, you can redirect to a host:port combination. Try this...it should do what you asked:

```
server {
  listen       85;
  listen       [::]:85;
  server_name  port123.host.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass         http://server85:123/;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}

server {
  listen       86;
  listen       [::]:86;
  server_name  port567.host.com

  location / {
    proxy_pass         http://server86:567/;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. it does. But I actually need also HTTPS so this complicates things. I'll update my question now.

Comment: Mmm...that seems rather unfair. I answer your question and then you change the question...? I think you should post a follow-up question for this.